# Протокол прикладного уровня поверх websockets

Tags: websocket

Есть ли протоколы прикладного уровня работающие поверх вебсокетов? Как я понимаю websocket как и tcp - потоковый, и хотелось бы избежать выдумывания своего протокола а использовать готовый

Answer (score 0):

@Semerkin по ws можно передавать как текст, так и бинарные данные, текстовые - любые - на вкус и цвет: json, xml, что-то своё. в этом вся прелесть ws.